# How to count repeated elements ahead in For loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a +50k list of data about angle measurements and I'd like to know when a value is repeating more than 8 times, for example. The problem is I don't want to look for repeated values in the whole column, but only when a value starts repeating for a certain frequency and then count this certain amount.

I thought in doing something really silly but the problem is it will find this amount of time but as I am doing it already inside a For loop, it will count this same event multiple times...

Also I'm trying to figure out a way that, after it discovers the count, the code jumps to the next non-repeated value in the For loop and resumes the loop.

```
  For i = 1 To n

    If Hour(Cells(i, 1).Value) >= Hour(7) And Hour(Cells(i, 1).Value) >= Hour(18) Then
        If Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = Cells(i + 2, 3).Value = Cells(i + 3, 3).Value = Cells(i + 4, 3).Value = Cells(i + 5, 3).Value = Cells(i + 6, 3).Value = Cells(i + 7, 3).Value Then
            'rest of code
        End If
    End If
 Next i
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Data sample:

[image: Sample]

Comment: Some sample data would go a long way here, I think.

Comment: `COUNTIFS` function may be of use here and also `Find` method (to find next non-repeating value).

Comment: @BigBen Sure, no problem. Do you think it's better to edit my question and put as a table in it?

Comment: Sure, that works. Just enough data so we more clearly understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

So the way you would generally do it for the whole list, is keep a frequency map. When the frequency gets too high, you stop printing that entry.

If you want to do the same over a window (of say say 50 rows) as you step through the file, then in your for-loop, you add each entry into the map, but you also decrement the count for the entry window-size before. Now you can make your decision to skip high-frequency rows.

To keep the storage tidy you might delete each value entry that decrements to zero frequency, or it may be faster to not keep reallocating them if the count grows again later in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

`=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,$B1)=1,IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$43,$B1)>8,"More",""),"")`